# Publishing the user access logs to Kafka through a custom HTTP service

Tags: logging, apache-kafka

Is it a common practice to ship the application logs from the server-side-rendered application to Kafka through the HTTP interface put in between? The logs volume can be significant and the delay should be minimal. Lost messages are not a big problem unless we loose a lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen guys using or I used the following approaches to push the application log to Apache Kafka.

[Async Log4J Appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#KafkaAppender) - assuming that you are using Log4J for logging.

Application log collection using [fluentd](https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/output/kafka)

Custom written Kafka file sink connect. An example is [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/filestream_connector.html).

I have seen companies in very strictly regulated industry writing custom log producers with async and local buffering capabilities to push logs to Kafka. They write the custom solution to either format the messages/encrypt or redact some information going out of their ecosystem.